# Use Linq to return all objects in a list where the object's sub-object-list property contains all values of an int list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of products.  Each product contains an attribute list.  The attribute list has 2 properties, optionId, and attributeSetId.  I first start with an int list of filtered optionId's.  I want to return all products that have optionIds that contain all the items in the list of filtered optionId's

```
class Product
{
   int Id;
   string Label;
   List<Attributes> attributes
}

class Attribute
{
   int optionId,
   int attributeSetId,
}

List<Products>() products;
List<>() filteredOptionIDs;
filteredOptionIds.Add(5);
filteredOptionIds.Add(34);
filteredOptionIds.Add(3456);
```

I need to return all products that have all the optionId's in the filteredOptionIds list

Edit -- Robert McKee example with Except() is the only one that worked for me.

```
var filteredProducts = products
  .Where(p=>!filteredOptionIds.Except(p.attributes.Select(a=>a.optionId)).Any());
```

Comment: First your code should be compilable. Make your fields public. etc. etc.

Comment: This is just pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails, this will work:

```
var filteredProducts = products.AsQueryable();
foreach(var option in filteredOptionIds)
  filteredProducts = filteredProducts.Where(r=>r.attributes.Select(att=>att.optionId).Contains(option));
```

This works by just repeatedly filtering down the results once for each option.  You can also use an expression builder.  There are so many different ways of accomplishing this task, the best approach really depends on what else you need/want to do with the query and what source it is coming from (database vs IEnumerable).

Another approach would look like this, but it may confuse some database LINQ providers, so test it before use:

```
var filteredProducts = products
  .Where(p=>!filteredOptionIds.Except(p.attributes.Select(a=>a.optionId)).Any());
```

This should also work:

```
var filteredProducts = products
    .Where(p=>filteredOptionIds.All(opt=>p.attributes.Any(att=>att.optionId==opt));
```

Comment: Hero.  Your second example with the Except() is the only one that works with the answers given so far.  Thank you!

Comment: Updated answer with a 3rd approach using All and Any. And updated the first answer to account for the attributes being a class and not a list of optionIds.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to make a where clause on products. The criteria is that all attribute.optionId should be present in the filteredOptionIDs. So you could use the contains from the filteredOptionIds. Then use the All so they all must be present.

You might try something like:  *(pseudo code)*

```
var filteredProducts = products
    .Where(prod => prod.attributes.All(att => filteredOptionIds.Contains(att.optionId));
```

Even faster is the use of the !Any:

```
var filteredProducts = products
    .Where(prod => !prod.attributes.Any(att => !filteredOptionIds.Contains(att.optionId));
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this linq query before and I only ever get the one same result.  Which is the 1 product in the DB that does not have any optionIds associated with it

Comment: We cannot see the data, nor that the data is from a DB

Comment: Both of these examples have their logic reversed. Not all product attributes need to be in the filtered list. All the options in the filtered list need to be in the product attributes.

Comment: That is what i'm reading here: _"I need to return all products that have all the optionId's in the filteredOptionIds list"_